# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

Tengo esta clase en java:

```
public class matriz {
    private int tamMatriz;
    private int[][] mainMatriz = new int[tamMatriz][tamMatriz];

    public matriz (int tamaño){
        tamMatriz = tamaño;

    }

    public void instanciarMatriz(){
        for (int i=0; i<=this.getTamaño()-1; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<=this.getTamaño()-1; j++){
                mainMatriz[i][j]=1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Y me tira el error pero no sé porqué razón puede llegar a ser! alguna idea?

Comment: Tu código está bien, se me ocurre que no has iniciado la matriz en el constructor: `int mainMatriz[][] = new int[tamMatriz][tamMatriz];`. Otra cosa, cambia "getTamaño", no uses "eñes" en aplicaciones, además... debes controlar que no se pueda introducir cero o menor que cero en `tamMatriz` ya que daría lugar a error en tu aplicación

Answer (score 1):

Facil, cuando creas el objeto, el valor de `tamMatriz` vale 0 por lo que crea una matriz vacía y al recorrerla `tamMatriz` ya ha sido asignado por lo que intenta recorrer elementos no existentes.

Lo que tienes que hacer es inicializar el array en el constructor despues de asignar el valor de `tamMatriz`.

```
public class matriz { 
    private int tamMatriz;
    private int[][] mainMatriz;

public matriz (int tamaño){
    tamMatriz = tamaño;
    mainMatriz = new int[tamMatriz][tamMatriz];    
}
public void instanciarMatriz(){
    for (int i=0; i<=this.getTamaño()-1; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<=this.getTamaño()-1; j++){
            mainMatriz[i][j]=1;
        }
    }
}
```

PD: Los nombres de las clases deben ir con la primera en mayúsculas segun las normas de estilo.